# How to integrate SharePoint list in model driven app in PowerApps?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, powerapps, model-driven-app

I have created many Canvas apps and integrate SharePoint list as data source in PowerApps. Now, i will need to create Modern Driven apps in PowerApps and get data from SharePoint list.

Do model-driven apps only run on Common Data Service (CDS) entities?  Or can they also run on data from other sources (like SharePoint lists or SQL Server tables)?

Can anyone help me for the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model-driven Apps run only on Dataverse (formerly Common Data Service) entities, thus you cannot directly reference a SharePoint list.

You can recreate the list as a Dataverse Table (formerly Entity). Then you could use Power Automate to keep the two lists synchronized. If the list will be read-only in the Model-driven App this will be simpler, but two-way sync is possible.

Another possibility, is creating a Canvas App that reads (and, if necessary, edits) the SharePoint list and embedding the Canvas App in your Model-driven App. This only works if there is no need for creating relationships between the Model-drive App records and the SharePoint List items.